# WP7 Disabled Button Style

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am trying to do change the color of a disabled button's border/text.

Code:

```
<Style x:Key="TopTabChooserButtonDisabled" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange" />
    </Style>
```

But it doesn't affect the button at all in Silverlight. Does anybody know what will make it change? THanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily by retemplating the control in blend.

Rclick the control, edit template, edit a copy. You then have access to all the states and constituent objects that make up the control in each of those states to change properties of each as needed.

Comment: Note for others: for those who never used Blend (like me), there is a tab called "states" where you can choose "disabled", then perform the necessary style changes.